What prevented fopen() from utilizing macros/flags but not fseek()?
In C, fopen() uses string literals such as "r" or "r+" or "w" to specify the mode with which to open a file. One possible reason for this I read is at the time C was so new that there might not have been a convenient way to create predefined constants.
However, the function fseek() which is part of the same file IO library uses predefined constants SEEK_SET SEEK_CUR and SEEK_END to specify the mode.
What was the motivation for using, at least what I consider a substandard approach for flag parameters for fopen() but not fseek()? If fseek() could use predefined constants as flags, why could fopen() not?

Where did you read this? Citation?

The natural way to use macro constants for fopen would have been with bitmasks, like Unix 'open' does. But I can't think of any place in the classic C standard library where bitmask constants are used, so maybe they wanted to avoid them for some reason.

I think, fseek() came later and probably the reason was that it used some file descriptor-based seek() syscall. But that is only hyphotese. Kerrigan could say, why has it so happened.

Questions about the history of a language might be more appropriate for [retrocomputing.se].

I agree that this API choice of using strings instead of some form of more structured data is maybe not great. But your question is about why should we expect a difference between these designs?
For fseek there really are only a handful of possibilities and there are unlikely to be more. But for fopen, many implementations of this library method support additional options in that string parameter. For example, to open a UTF-8 text file:
FILE *fp = fopen("newfile.txt", "rt+, ccs=UTF-8");

Microsoft's implementation has dozens of extensions to the string argument; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-170 for a list.
In short, it's an extension point for standard library implementations to take advantage of. Whether that was a motivation for the design, or a happy historical accident, I do not know.
